Short-lived 2000s TV series about a guy released from prison
The TV series was cancelled in the middle of season 2 (bad story line, goofs, not enough viewers).

One of the biggest goofs is that one character died in an earlier episode, then appeared again in the show later (as the same character)
The main character just got out of prison and some dirty cops were pushing him to do bad stuff
He had a sister (which he was trying to protect, don't remember from what)
In the show the actor is Hispanic/Latino (I think he is the same in real life)
In the show the actor is tall and buffed
He wears a white, long sleeves sweater usually (tight on the body)
He has short hair, and a little small beard above the mouth and the chin
The character's name is Johnny... something... in the show (IF I REMEMBER CORRECTLY, I might be wrong)
The intro song of the show has a resemblance to the John Cena song 'My Time Is Now'


P.S. Someone should probably note you changed your name here after learning the answer, lest people think you're winding them up. ;)

How can we do that?
PS: i just changed my name in the TV series to make sure I never forget it :D I don't want it to mess with my mind again, ehehehe

"How can we do that?" That's OK, I just did. ;)

Great.
Thanks again for your help!

Sounds like FOX's Jonny Zero from 2005, though it only lasted 1 season.

An ex-con wants to start an honest life. His old crime outfit wants him, as well as an FBI agent who's working on a case against his former partners in crime. All he wants is to regain his family's trust and help those in need.

Jonny (played by Franky G) looks exactly as you described him. Here's the intro:




You're the man!!! Thanks a lot

@Baloo No problem :) BTW, the continuity errors weren't their fault. FOX just aired the episodes out of order (which is something they do a lot).

I was off track with some of the details and hints

the thing about goofs is something that stuck in my mind when I've read a review in the past, apparently it was not reliable :)

